# Create a new column based on whether one columns values are greater than another

Tags: dplyr, case, mutate

I am trying to create a column that shows when the value (i.e. time) from one column (fishing_effort_start_date_time) is greater (i.e. at a later time) than the value of another column (POSITION_DATETIME_NZ). I am using the following script:

```
travel_pot <- gpr_df_R %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  group_by(vessel_name) %>% 
  droplevels() %>% 
  mutate(trip_pot=case_when(fishing_effort_start_date_time > POSITION_DATETIME_NZ 
                            ~"travel", T~"potting"))

travel_pot
```

It creates the column but the results in the travel_pot column are incorrect for example:
[image: see image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are grouping the data twice, first with `rowwise()` and then overriding that with a `group_by()`.  You should call `rowwise()` right before you do the`mutate()`

Comment: Nope, that didn't change anything. I think I need to change the class of the two variables to a date/time object

Answer (score 0):

As you have suggested, it may be because your datetime columns are not in the correct format. If your datetime columns are not in the correct format, you can run something like:

```
gpr_df_R$POSITION_DATETIME_NZ <- as.POSIXct(gpr_df_R$POSITION_DATETIME_NZ, 
                                            format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
                                            tz = "nz")
```

and just repeat for all your datetime columns. Here is a repex. Based on your example data, you should not need `group_by()` or `rowwise()`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
from1 <- as.POSIXct("01/10/2019 08:50:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "nz")
to1 <- as.POSIXct("01/10/2019 10:30:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "nz")
fesdt <- as.POSIXct("01/10/2019 08:40:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "nz")
feedt <- as.POSIXct("01/10/2019 14:17:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "nz")

gpr_df_R <- data.frame(POSITION_DATETIME_NZ = seq(from = from1, by = 600, to = to1),
                       fishing_effort_start_date_time = fesdt,
                       fishing_effort_end_date_time = feedt)

# Create new column
travel_pot <- gpr_df_R %>%
  mutate(trip_pot = case_when(fishing_effort_start_date_time > 
                                POSITION_DATETIME_NZ ~ "travel",
                              TRUE ~ "potting"))

   POSITION_DATETIME_NZ fishing_effort_start_date_time fishing_effort_end_date_time trip_pot
1   2019-10-01 08:50:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
2   2019-10-01 09:00:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
3   2019-10-01 09:10:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
4   2019-10-01 09:20:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
5   2019-10-01 09:30:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
6   2019-10-01 09:40:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
7   2019-10-01 09:50:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
8   2019-10-01 10:00:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
9   2019-10-01 10:10:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
10  2019-10-01 10:20:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
11  2019-10-01 10:30:00            2019-10-01 08:40:00          2019-10-01 14:17:00  potting
```

Answer (score 0):

Does trip_pot only have two potential values? If so, it's better and simpler to use a TRUE/FALSE column:

```
mutate(gpr_df_R, trip_pot = fishing_effort_start_datetime > position_datetime_nz)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 11 × 4
   position_datetime_nz fishing_effort_start_d…¹ fishing_effort_end_d…² trip_pot
   <dttm>               <dttm>                   <dttm>                 <lgl>   
 1 2019-10-01 08:50:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
 2 2019-10-01 09:00:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
 3 2019-10-01 09:10:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
 4 2019-10-01 09:20:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
 5 2019-10-01 09:30:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
 6 2019-10-01 09:40:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
 7 2019-10-01 09:50:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
 8 2019-10-01 10:00:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
 9 2019-10-01 10:10:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
10 2019-10-01 10:20:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE   
11 2019-10-01 10:30:00  2019-10-01 08:40:00      2019-10-01 14:17:00    FALSE
```

Data:

```
gpr_df_R <- tibble(
    position_datetime_nz = seq(ymd_hms("2019-10-01 08:50:00"), ymd_hms("2019-10-01 10:30:00"), by = "10 min"),
    fishing_effort_start_datetime = ymd_hms("2019-10-01 08:40:00"),
    fishing_effort_end_datetime = ymd_hms("2019-10-01 14:17:00"))
```